# Which point on the line $ 2x-3y+3=0$ is nearest to the point $(-1,9)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Which point on the line $2x-3y+3=0$ is nearest to the point $(-1,9)$.

I've tried to use the distance formula... (2×(-1)-3×9+3)/√(4+9) =  26/√13

The right answer: (3,3)

How can I get it?

Comment: Please elaborate on how you used the distance formula.

Comment: (2×(-1)-3×9+3)/√(4+9) =  26/√13

Answer (score 4):

You can write the line as $y = \frac{2x}{3} + 1$. So, the distance from $(-1,9)$ to $\left(x,\frac{2x}{3} + 1\right)$ is given by: $$d(x) = \sqrt{\left(x +1\right)^2 +  \left(\frac{2x}{3} + 1 - 9\right)^2}$$

Minimizing this function is the same as minimizing its square (why?), the function $$f(x) = \left(x+1\right)^2 + \left(\frac{2x}{3} - 8 \right)^2$$

See what happens when $f '(x) = 0$.

(Note: there are easier ways to solve this, but since "calculus" is a tag here, I suppose this solution using derivatives would be better)

Answer (score 2):

I will give a hint. The point you want to find is the intersection of the given line $2x - 3y + 3 = 0$ and a line perpendicular to it and passing through given point $(-1, 9)$. try to find equation of this perpendicular line.

Answer (score 2):

Line $2x-3y+3=0$ in explicite form is$$l_1:y=\frac{2}{3}x+1$$ we need $l_2:y=kx+n$ such that $l_2$ is perpendicular to $l_1$ which contain also the point $(-1,9)$ so
$$l_2:y=-\frac{3}{2}x+n$$
because $(-1,9)\in l_2\Rightarrow9=\frac{-3}{2}\cdot(-1)+n\Rightarrow n=\frac{15}{2}$

Finally solve the system
$$l_1:y=\frac{2}{3}x+1$$
$$l_2:y=-\frac{3}{2}x+\frac{15}{2}$$
you get $x=3,y=3$ that means the point $(3,3)\in l_2$ is nearest to $(-1,9)$
$$d((-1,9),(3,3))=2\sqrt{13}$$

Comment: Yes, I know, but how can I find the points? Thank you anyway.

Comment: Ivo Terek gave you the answer. Compute $f'(x)$ and make it equal to $0$. This will give you $x$ and the equation of the line will give you $y$.